# Risks / costs of useless casts?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

(Env: Linux / RTOS, Compiler: gcc v.7.3.1)

Is there a risk or cost to useless casts?

Here's an example:

Project.h:

```
typedef int32 PRJ_Status_t;
...
#define PRJ_SUCCESS((PRJ_Status_t)0)
```

Project.cpp:

```
#include "Project.h" 
bool ProjectApp::init()
{
   ...
   return(status == static_cast<int32>(PRJ_SUCCESS));
}
```

Comment: Your question code be reduced to *"Is there a risk or cost to useless casts `static_cast<T>(T{}))`?"*

Comment: The greatest risk is that whoever maintains the code will be burning time chasing down snipes.

Comment: The main risk of a "useless" in your situation is that someone will change the macro `PRJ_SUCCESS` to something else, so the cast forces the compiler to silently accept what would otherwise be an invalid conversion.   That opens the door for undefined behaviour with symptoms that may only be detected at run time (or, worse, only detected by an end user rather than detected at compile time).

Comment: Short answer: No, unless the cast is from `float` to `int` or vice versa, except for extra typing and/or confusion.

Comment: It's pretty common to see people asking questions on StackOverflow about runtime misbehavior in their code, and in their posted code there is a cast that was placed there to override the compiler's judgement and silence a warning/error that was pointing out the problem in the line containing the bug.  Removing the cast from the buggy code brings the warning/error message back, at which point it becomes easier to understand and properly fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

All casts except for `dynamic_cast` are performed at compilation time, so there is no cost to them during runtime. The risks are inherent to the casting itself - it's forcing by definition, overriding the automatic safety mechanisms of the language. In case of "useless" cast, the only risk is impact on readability and maintenance of the code.

Comment: Some static casts involve adjustments to values at runtime -- narrowing conversions and, sometimes, pointer adjustments when converting between pointer-to-base and pointer-to-derived (both directions) come to mind. And, of course, any class that has a user-defined conversion may well end up doing a runtime calculation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no runtime cost for this `static_cast`. There is a cognitive cost, though, in terms of taking more effort to understand the code.

Is there a risk? Well, let's do a comparison of casting to not casting. Here's your code dressed up for copy-compile-run to contrast the behaviors with and without a cast. (I had to guess the type of `status`. I chose what the cast is to, namely `int32_t`, but `PRJ_Status_t` would work equally well in this demonstration.)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef int32_t PRJ_Status_t;

#define PRJ_SUCCESS ((PRJ_Status_t)0)

// ----------------------------------

bool init_cast()
{
   int32_t status = 0;
   return(status == static_cast<int32_t>(PRJ_SUCCESS));
}

bool init_bare()
{
   int32_t status = 0;
   return(status == PRJ_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "The result with casting is " << init_cast() << ".\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "The result without cast is " << init_bare() << ".\n";
}
```

Running this produces

```
The result with casting is true.
The result without cast is true.
```

Looks good. Oh wait, the lead designer has made a change. Due to some expected growth of your organization, the status needs to be expanded to 64 bits with your project number stored in the upper 32 bits. Your project is number 1, so you modify `Project.h` accordingly. Only the code above commented separator has changed.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef uint64_t PRJ_Status_t;

#define PRJ_SUCCESS ((PRJ_Status_t)((1ULL << 32)))

// ----------------------------------

bool init_cast()
{
   int32_t status = 0;
   return(status == static_cast<int32_t>(PRJ_SUCCESS));
}

bool init_bare()
{
   int32_t status = 0;
   return(status == PRJ_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "The result with casting is " << init_cast() << ".\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "The result without cast is " << init_bare() << ".\n";
}
```

No sweat. The output is still good, right?

```
The result with casting is true.
The result without cast is false.
```

Your mileage may vary. Maybe ignoring the project number is the right thing to do. It shouldn't matter that you accidentally invoked a function not associated with your project to get the status, right?

Answer (score 0):

Cost at runtime? No. Casting a `int32_t` to a `int32_t` does nothing.

---

Apart from that...

A `static_cast` is a signpost for the reader of the code. It alerts them to be cautious about what is happening in that line. If someone reads

```
return(status == static_cast<int32>(PRJ_SUCCESS));
```

They will wonder what the actual type of `PRJ_SUCCESS` is. It will take them two lookups, one to find the macro that defined `PRJ_SUCCESS` and another one to find the declaration of the type alias. All that only to experience a WTF-moment. They could have used their time for more useful things. Suppose you are looking for a bug in the code, the more WTF-moments there are in the code, the more time it will take to find a bug.

Answer (score -1):

No. Any halfway decent compiler will simply do nothing for a "useless" cast.

Observe:

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef int32_t PRJ_Status_t;

#define PRJ_SUCCESS ((PRJ_Status_t)0)

#ifdef DO_CAST
#define cast(x) static_cast<int32_t>(x)
#pragma message "with cast"
#else
#define cast(x) (x)
#pragma message "without cast"
#endif

bool init()
{
   int32_t status=55;
   return(status == cast(PRJ_SUCCESS));
}
```

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -DDO_CAST -S Test.cpp -o - | wc -l
Test.cpp:9:17: note: ‘#pragma message: with cast’
    9 | #pragma message "with cast"
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
45
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -S Test.cpp -o - | wc -l
Test.cpp:12:17: note: ‘#pragma message: without cast’
   12 | #pragma message "without cast"
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
45
```

Both versions produce 45 lines of assembler code. Now, while this doesn't really prove anything, it's a strong hint it's the same code.

Also, while your mileage may vary -- the C++ standard does not mandate that has to be the same code -- any decent compiler will recognize that it's "pointless" to make that cast, and just ignore it.

An actually more interesting question arises if a cast is "useless" today, but is not "useless" on, let's say, another platform. If, for example, your `PRJ_Status_t` ends up being `int64_t`, your previously useless cast will just convert it silently. Without the cast, you would have gotten a warning if you assign it to an `int32_t`...

Comment: Regarding another platform - that's not necessary a problem. Could be an intentional simple compile-time polymorphism. But that depends on the design, of course

Comment: Yeah, I just felt I should mention it as something that a "useless cast" can actually affect.